# Why doesn't changing the Discount Rate change IRR?

Tags: real-estate, rate-of-return

I have an analysis for a real estate project done and I'm changing the discount rate but IRR is not affected.  I don't understand why this is...?  It seems that changing the discount rate would change the NPV, changing the point where NPV=0.

Comment: Is this a homework problem in an economics or accounting course or a prep course for a real estate broker license exam?

Answer (score 8):

Because the IRR doesn't depend on discount rate.

Instead, the IRR is a discount rate.

The IRR is the discount rate that makes the NPV=0.

Put another way, the IRR is the discount rate that causes projects to break even.

Raising or lowering the discount rate in a project does not affect the rate that would have caused it to break even.

Comment: Thanks, Paul.  I should get it in my mind that NPV calculations and IRR are separate.  For some reason I keep mixing them.

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon. My situation is that I have a degree in real estate finance....from 18 years ago.  I'm getting back into real estate and some things are coming back quickly and I have holes in other places.  In school we focused on IRR and FMRR.

When I have an investor who wants a 12% return on a building purchase I just use DCF at 12% to get the target purchase price.  I know that if that's the price it's bought at then NPV = 0 = discount rate.  That's the break even point of the investment. (more continued)

Comment: "Raising or lowering the discount rate in a project does not affect the rate that would have caused it to break even."  This is probably my hole.  In my mind if you are paying 15% interest and you find a new loan at 5% interest then your cost of capital (discount rate) changes and your IRR would change as well.  Can you explain more about how the break even point is not affected?

Comment: Moi, suppose there is a real estate project with IRR=6%.  The investor finds a loan with rate=3%, therefore he believes the investment will be profitable since NPV(r) should be positive for r below IRR%.  However, it turns out the loan was an adjustable loan that changes after 1 month to 7.99%.  Now the investor should know that since 7.99% is above IRR=6% the project will have negative NPV and therefore yield a loss.  The fact that the loan rate changed does not affect that the IRR was 6% and that with financing at 6%, NPV would be zero (break even).

Comment: There is an analogy with household budget.  If Fred needs $3,500/month salary to break even on his household bills, we mean that at that salary of $3500/mo he has exactly no money left over.  If S is the salary, we could say his disposable income is S-3500.  If his salary goes down to $2000/mo, his disposable income is 2000-3500=-1500 and he still needs $3500/mo to break even.  If his salary goes up to $4000/mo, his disposable income is now 4000-3500=500 and that is good, he needed $3500/mo to break even. The break even math is the same.  It is only a model, as real people do adjust spending..

Comment: Thanks again, Paul.  The example that's always used is the $1,000 investment that pays off $200 (or whatever) for 6 years, plus a residual.  I thought the calculation for IRR was discounting the cash flows by the discount rate that you choose.  I now know that's not the case.  I was doing the formulas in Excel which is where I saw there was no discount rate.  That's why you have to "guess" as to what it will be, it's not something that's given.

Comment: in excel you don't have to guess the rate in irr, its optional.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a schedule of discount rates then the IRR you seeking is the interest rate at which net present value of the investment discounted using a schedule of rates is the same as the net present value of investment using a single rate. Think of this a interest rate shocks over the term of the investment and the investor is seeking a single rate that will offer the same return on investment as those offered by the schedule of discount rates.

See these two links

[Excel IRR Schedule function](http://tadxl.com/excel_irr_function_with_rate_schedule.html)

[Excel IRR function](http://tadxl.com/excel_irr_function.html)